In my nodejs project where I use prisma orm, I sometimes get too many connections error in mysql, this error goes away when the ip is changed
as I wrote in the title, I am using prisma orm in my nodejs (nestjs) project. Sometimes I get the too many connections error. This error keeps happening, but when I change the IP, this error gets fixed. I don't think I'm stuck with the connection limit in Mysql. If that were the case, I think changing the IP would not fix it. I leave my prisma orm connection code below. Does anyone know what could be causing such an error and why it can be fixed when the IP is changed?
@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient {
  [x: string]: any;
  async enableShutDownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
    this.process.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
      await app.close();
    });
  }
}

